# Fortran77 compiler for codeblocks (win10 64bits)?

Tags: codeblocks, fortran77

I am a chemical engineering student trying to figure out how to use fortran77. I'm a newbie to programming. I have tried to use openwatcom compiler since it's known for fortran 77, but the "main" file for the fortran DLL project is still in .f95. I don't know how to change it to .f77.

Tried OpenWatcom IDE, error message: "No such file or directory". But I have set target and source. Don't know why

Also 64bit win10 should run 32bit application, right? Don't know why it doesn't work. Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Try this link, simplyfortran.com/links/ and find a good version with Windows installer. I'll try it myself this evening.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will give it a try.